# Wordpress get_template_part extract parameters before template is fired

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to extract the get_template_part params ($args) for every template I use. But I am ending creating "global" variables that are available in all templates at the end. I know why, but I don't know how to change it. Hopefully I will get help from the community.

I have this code:

```
get_template_part($shortPaths[$template], "", $params);
```

$shortPaths[$template] = Path to a php file.

$params = ["title" => "Hello"];

Now i have created an add_action

```
function test ($slug, $name, $template, $args) {
    if ($args) {
        extract($args);
    }

}

add_action('get_template_part', 'test', 10, 4);
```

And when I read this out in my template it works, but the `$title` is also available in other templates now and I don't want to reset it in every template, because then I also could use `get_query_var` and `set_query_var`

I saw that there is also a hook called `get_template_part_{$slug}`, but this would maybe only helpful, when the template is not used more than once.

Does anybody has an idea, how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can absolutely not tell what you want to _achieve_ by this. Please give a proper explanation, what the purpose of this whole process is supposed to be to begin with.

Comment: I don't want to use $args['title'] and the other params. I want to use $title only.

Comment: Other than doing `extract($args);` directly at the beginning of your template file(s), I don't see any other quick solution for this.